# Dropdown list showing SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DONSERVER instead of Active Directory group name in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

Here's the problem. The dropdown list in my view in an application I'm working on is showing `SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$DONSERVER` instead of the actual Active Directory group name. I'm posting here for the first time. Personally I have never ran into this issue. I'm hoping someone with experience with this can help out. I have posted the relevant code below.

Code to get all Active Directory groups (note: the code is located in another model):

```
public List<GroupsModel> PopulateGroups(GroupsModel groupsModel)
{
    List<GroupsModel> GetGroups = new List<GroupsModel>();

    // create your domain context
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

    // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
    GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

    // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
    PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

    // find all matches
    foreach (var found in srch.FindAll())
    {
        // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....
        groupsModel.SamAccountName = found.SamAccountName;
        groupsModel.Description = found.Description;
        groupsModel.DistinguishedName = found.DistinguishedName;

        GetGroups.Add(groupsModel);
    }

    return GetGroups;
}
```

Here is the markup associated with retrieving the Active Directory groups - note: at the top of the page I have...

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;,
@model Active_Directory_Manager.Models.MainPageModel
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

At the modal section of my view I'm using this chunk of code.

```
@{
    Active_Directory_Manager.Models.GroupsLists groupLists = new  Active_Directory_Manager.Models.GroupsLists();
    Active_Directory_Manager.Models.GroupsModel groupsModel = new Active_Directory_Manager.Models.GroupsModel();
}

@foreach (var item in groupLists.PopulateGroups(groupsModel))
{
    <select class="input-lg" style="">
        <option value="0" style="color:#ccc !important;">
            Please select a group to join to...
        </option>
        <option value="@item.SamAccountName">@item.SamAccountName</option>
    </select>
}
```

Thank you in advance if anyone can help me out. In the meantime I'll do my best to solve this problem.

I have tried several things to help solve my problem. I tried using the `private List<GroupsModel>` outside of the `public List<GroupsModel> PopulateGroups` method and also tried using it inside of that method as well.

I also tried to access the list via the `@Model.ModelName` (for example) but the model kept coming up null while in debug mode.

Comment: To help narrow it down, do you know whether the problem is in the controller or the view? If not, put a breakpoint (or log) on this line: `groupsModel.Description = found.Description;` When it hits, check the value of `groupsModel.SamAccountName`. If the value is correct, it's likely a view problem, else it's likely a controller problem.

Comment: I actually ended up solving the problem. The problem was that I had a List<GroupModel> instead of List<string> which solved the issue. I'm now getting all Active Directory Groups.

Answer (score 0):

I actually ended up solving this issue myself. The problem was I had `List<GroupModel>` instead of `List<string>`. I changed it to `List<string>` and got all Active Directory Groups. Thanks :D